# Retrieve records having partial string match for a key from IndexDB

Tags: javascript, database

I have my contact details JSON objects stored in indexDB. There is a field for "birthdate" which is stored in `04/05/2014` (`dd/mm/yyyy`) format.

I want to retrieve record by matching `dd/mm` only.
I want to retrieve all contacts who have a particular birthday (regardless of year).

Comment: Some more info would be helpful. How are you currently getting your data back? What have you tried already?

Comment: This is how my object look like {name:"sac",birthdate:"04/05/2014"}.Currently i am getting all the contacts from indexdb then iterating it and checking it if a person has birthday on a perticular date. Basically i want retrive all records who have birthdays on a perticular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a lot of ways to approach this.
what you could do is create a function that will parse just the dd/mm out of the column

then in the where clause say @user_entry = dbo.fnc_GetDDMM(table.jsoncol)

the function could just leverage index of and substrings to pull out anything after DOB: DD/MM 
with the example you provided it could look something like

```
if object_id('dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson', 'fn') is not null
begin
    print 'drop: dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson'
    drop function dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson
end
go

print 'create: dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson'
go

create function dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson
(
    @json varchar(500)
)  
returns date
as  
begin 
    --declare @json varchar(500) = '{name:"sac",birthdate:"04/05/2014"}',

declare @birthday date
declare @birthdaystring varchar(50) = 'birthdate:"'

declare @blen int = len(@birthdaystring)
declare @bindex int = charindex(@birthdaystring, @json)




    set @birthday= substring(@json, @bindex + @blen, 10)

    return @birthday
end
```

then your where could look like this

```
select * --dont use '*' but just an example
from sometable as table
where datepart(month, dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson(table.jsoncolumn)) == @somemonth 
and datepart(year, dbo.GetBirthdayFromJson(table.jsoncolumn)) == @someyear
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply man. This is how my object look like {name:"sac",birthdate:"04/05/2014"}.Currently i am getting all the contacts from indexdb then iterating it and checking it if a person has birthday on a perticular date. Basically i want retrive all records who have birthdays on a perticular date. I don'n want to get all contacts and then iterate through it. If it could possible i want to get all the contacts who have birthdays on a perticular date.

Comment: @ScorpioKing, updated my answer with a function that could work for you. it may need some fine tuning for your specific needs but should get you close to what you want.

Comment: note: this assumes that the len of the date will always be 10! you can add some more index checks to make that a little more dynamic if needed

Comment: @ScorpioKing, hope this worked for you. if it did i would thank you for making this question as answered